# Why are consequent chained promises resolved?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am trying to get my head around Promises/A+ and I am confused on a couple of points. Consider this:

```
function foo() {
    console.log("In 'foo' function: --> which returns a Promise");
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve()
    });
}

var promise1 = foo();

var promise2 = promise1.then(function () {
    console.log("Promise 1 has been resolved --> onFulfilled() returns a value");
    return 1;
});

var promise3 = promise2.then(function () {
    console.log("Promise 2 has been resolved --> onFulfilled() is not returning anything from inFulfilled()");
});

var promise4 = promise3.then(function () {
    console.log("Promise 3 has been resolved");
});

/* Console:
In 'foo' function: --> which returns a Promise
Promise 1 has been resolved --> onFulfilled() returns a value
Promise 2 has been resolved --> onFulfilled() is not returning anything from inFulfilled()
Promise 3 has been resolved
*/
```

- Promise 1 has to be explicitly resolved by calling `resolve()`, otherwise the execution halts. Why is it that, with Promises 2 and 3 the execution considers these resolved (without requiring `resolve()`) and progresses to the next `.then` in the chain?
- The'onFullfilled()' function chained to promise2, does not return a value. I cannot find any clear [reference](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-40) in the spec what is supposed to happen in this case. Is this scenario treated as if the function returned [undefined](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-8)? Is this down to the actual implementation of the library used?

Comment: In JavaScript not returning anything is same as `return undefined` which means you resolve the promise with `undefined`. The caller cannot tell the difference between forgotten return and explicit `return undefined` so it is not up the implementation. If it could then it would be fantastic because forgotten return statement is most common promise bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Promise handlers (success or error handler) have a return value. Each then call creates a new promise.

If a value is returned, then the promise is auto-resolved.  If another promise is returned, then the promise will wait until it is either resolved or rejected before continuing the next then call in the promise chain.

I think this explains the behaviour you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're looking for is here at #7 (https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec#the-then-method) in the promise/A+ spec.

`promise2 = promise1.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);`

"If either onFulfilled or onRejected returns a value x, run the Promise Resolution Procedure [[Resolve]](promise2, x)."

What I take away from this is that when the first promise is failed/resolved, any promise created from it (including the new promise `promise2`), is failed/resolved.

*eg:* When you resolve `promise1` in your example, all the subsequent promises also resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I did some small tweaks to your code:

- Pass a parameter to `resolve(data)` e.g. `resolve(1001)`
- In the `.then` retrieve and display the data
- Also in the `.then` return the next Promise in the chain with `return new Promise`

Here's your example reworked:

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log("Creating Promise 1");
    resolve( 1001 );
} );

var promise2 = promise1.then(function (data1) {
    console.log("Promise 1 has been resolved --> ", data1);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("Creating Promise 2");
        resolve( 1002 );
    } );
} );

var promise3 = promise2.then(function (data2) {
    console.log("Promise 2 has been resolved --> ", data2);
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log("Creating Promise 3");
        resolve( 1003 );
    } );
} );

promise3.then(function (data3) {
    console.log("Promise 3 has been resolved --> ", data3);
} );
```